# Как добавить адаптивное изображение в QLabel?

Tags: qt, изображения, qt5, qtcreator, qt4

Необходимо добавить изображение в один layout в `QtDesigner'e`, чтобы оно не превышало размеры layout'a. Т.е. при изменении размера окна, layout будет меняться, а с ним и все его компоненты, включая изображение.

Видел решение с помощью `QPixmap` в `QLabel`, но там изображение гигантское получается, а мне надо `"адаптивное"` изображение.

Comment: предоставьте пожалуйста ваш `.ui`  файл.

Comment: Просто у QLabel есть слот setPixmap(), а так можно QPainter'ом рисовать на виджетах через paintEvent(). Тогда ты сможешь его масштабировать, сохраняя пропорции. Я, кстати, не люблю дизайнером пользоваться. Говорят так быстрее, но по-моему это фигня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В layout добавить изображение не получится, у него другая специализация. Все-таки придется поработать с `QLabel`.

По умолчанию произвольно масштабировать изображение в `QLabel` не получится, потому что при установке изображения, `QLabel` устанавливает свой минимальный размер равный размеру изображения, поэтому надо ее (метку) подправить с помощью наследования.

Заголовочный файл FixPixmapLabel.h:

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QResizeEvent>

class FitPixmapLabel : public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FitPixmapLabel(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    // Метод возвращающий минимальный размер метки
    // Если в метке есть изображение, то возвращает его размер
    // а нам надо, чтобы было QSize(0, 0), поэтому переопределяем
    QSize minimumSizeHint() const override;
protected:
    // Переопределяем метод изменения размера метки, в котором будем
    // подгонять наше изображение к новому размеру метки
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override;
};
```

Реализация FitPixmapLabel.cpp:

```
#include "FitPixmapLabel.h"

FitPixmapLabel::FitPixmapLabel(QWidget* parent = nullptr) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
}

QSize FitPixmapLabel::minimumSizeHint() const {
    return QSize(0, 0);
}

void FitPixmapLabel::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) {
    
    // Статический объект source нужен, чтобы хранить изначальное,
    // неиспорченное множеством трансформаций, изображение
    static QPixmap source;

    // Инициализируем source
    if ( source.isNull() && pixmap() != nullptr )
        source = QPixmap(*pixmap());

 
    if( !source.isNull() ) {
        // Гладенько трансформируем изображение под новый размер метки 
        // с сохранением пропорций (если не надо то, замените Qt::KeepAspectRatio на что-нибудь другое)
        QPixmap p = source.scaled(event->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
         // Обновляем изображение в метке
        setPixmap(p);
    }
    QLabel::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Далее, в редакторе QtDesigner выбираем любой QLabel, нажимаем `ПКМ` и выбираем пункт `"Преобразовать в..."` и далее, в появившемся диалоге, вводим в поле `"Имя преобразованного класса"` имя нашего класса `FitPixmapLabel`. Далее, либо программно, либо там же в редакторе добавляем изображение, которое будет заполнять все свободное пространство метки, сохраняя пропорции.

Comment: Alexander доходчиво +

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Но у меня что-то не получается. Я создал .cpp файл с Вашим кодом, создал QLabel в редакторе и преобразовал его в класс FitPixmapLabel, но компилятор выдает мне абсолютно нечитаемую ошибку...
Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, еще чуть точнее объяснить?

Comment: @Sazoks мой код надо поместить в заголовочный h-файл (FitPixmapLabel.h) , а из  cpp-файла (FitPixmapLabel. cpp) все удалить

Comment: Так тоже делал - не работает.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, компилятор ругается на конструктор копирования в классе FitPixmapLabel:
ошибка: C2664: "FitPixmapLabel::FitPixmapLabel(const FitPixmapLabel &)": ­Ґў®§¬®¦­® ЇаҐ®Ўа §®ў вм  аЈг¬Ґ­в 1 Ё§ "QWidget *" ў "const FitPixmapLabel &"

Comment: @Sazoks уточнил ответ. Если будут какие-либо проблемы, то выкладывайте с ошибкой, а то навыки чревовещания у меня на низком уровне

Comment: @Sazoks нет, нужен конструктор по умолчанию. Обновил ответ

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо! Это сработало, однако только при уменьшении окна. Если окно растягивать, то изображение сохраняет последний меньший размер размер.

Comment: @Sazoks по нормальному, надо бы из этого класса делать виджет-плагин и работать через qtcreator. А так, смотрите,  что там у вас с лейаутами и так далее, все должно работать и в уменьшение и в увеличение